# NumPy: Masking an array based on another mask

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm filtering an array based on a given mask but I also want to preserve original shape. Till now, I was AND-ing every mask and using that mask as my final mask. But the first filter is special, as it will remove NANs from the original array.

Consider this toy example

```py
a = np.array([1,0,-1,2,0])

b = a != 1
c = a[b] != 0
c &= a[b] == 2
```

The output after this code block is `[False False  True False]`. However, I want to achieve `[False False False  True False]`. Thus the result would only point to `2`.

I thought I could OR `b`and `c` but the masks are not contiguous. The problem here is that I can't do a for-loop here because the original array contains over 1 million elements and there are more than 10 filters. So it would be nice to know how can I utilize NumPy's broadcast capabilities.

Comment: Can you please explain in a bit more detail why anding the masks doesn't work? If NaNs are an issue maybe give an example that includes NaNs. For the example you've given `mask = (a!=1) & (a!=0) & (a==2)` would give you what you have put as your desired output.

Comment: Yes you are right. The exact problem behind my original situation is that the masks I `AND` are operations that won't work with NANs inside the input array. So the solution I desire shouldn't combine `a != 1` mask but use it as input array for other masks.

Comment: Use `np.isnan` to test for `nan`.  Beware than an array with `nan` will be float.  = testing for floats is trickier .  `np.isclose` is safer.

Comment: I still don't understand why @MichaelCG8 's solution won't work here. If `a!=1` should act as a filter that should select the elements for which the mask is being computed, then you can do `(a!=1) & (<other filters here>)`. Do you mean that it is invalid to perform the desired computation on elements where `a==1`? If so, could you please update your example so that we can get a better sense of what you are up to?

Comment: I might've not explained my problem well, but I think I've found my solution with `b[b==True] &= c`

Comment: @DenizdaKing, we try to get solutions on the site so that when other people come looking with the same problem they have something there. I'm glad you've figured out something that works for you, but please still edit your question to add an example input and output that includes NaN's, then we can add an answer that other people can see too.